# How can I disable a specific row and prevent clicking in a data grid Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datagrid

I have created a data grid, three column inside, `firstName`, `lastName`, and `age`. I want to disable the specific row when the age value is less than `18`. How can I achieve that? I have done some research online https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/windowsforms/Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.WinForms~Syncfusion.WinForms.DataGrid.SfDataGrid~CurrentCellActivating_EV.html and it says the event to handle this situation is `CurrentCellActivating` so I have created a method as following:

```cs
private void DataGrid_DisableSpecifcRow(object sender, CurrentCellActivatingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

This is what I have so far in my XAML.

```
    <datagrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Padding="0,20" GridTapped="Handle_GridTapped" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectionMode="Single" BackgroundColor="Transparent" QueryRowStyle="DataGrid_QueryRowStyle">
        </datagrid:SfDataGrid>
```

However, I just don't know how to disable the specific row. Using the `e`, there is no option like `e.RowIndex.IsEnabled = false`. Any comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this to see if it works but I think something similar to the below should work.  The IF statement to check the age may need to altered but the rest should be okay.

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[5].Age < 18)
            {
                 e.Row.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But what is the event that I need to put inside XAML to support the GridViewRowEventArgs? Currently I have             <datagrid:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Padding="0,20" GridTapped="Handle_GridTapped" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SelectionMode="Single" BackgroundColor="Transparent" QueryRowStyle="DataGrid_QueryRowStyle" CurrentCellActivating="DataGrid_DisableSpecifcRow">

Comment: Are you getting an error with the above code? If so, what is the error message relating to GridViewEventArgs?

Comment: The type of namespace name 'GridViewRowEventArgs' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? The potential fix just ask me to create a new class for it.

Comment: Do you mind posting the current code you have if this is not resolved yet? Might be missing an import or updaye NuGet packages with 'Update-Package –reinstall'